# How to Truncate a Table with Partitions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to truncate a table using partitions.

```
SET @Sql =( 'TRUNCATE TABLE _result.result
WITH (PARTITIONS (SELECT PartitionNumber FROM #temp2 ))
GO');
Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

And,I am getting this Error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

In, my temp table there are so many PartitionNumber that's why I am using select statement with Partitions.

Comment: `SELECT` statements can't be used to replace a literal. Also `GO` is not a T-SQL keyword, and would also generate an error. `GO` is an SSMS/`sqlcmd` keyword for and separates statements into different batches.

Comment: In, my temp table there are so many PartitionNumber that's why I was using select statement with Partitions. I thought it can be done by this way.

Comment: You can not apply condition in truncate.

Comment: You'll have build your dynamic statement and ***safely*** inject the values into it. (I *cannot* stress the word ***safely*** enough here).

Comment: @SurajKumar is there any way to do this?

Comment: @SumitTiwary No in that case you need to run delete statement which will not reset the identity key. Please check this post https://www.sqlshack.com/difference-between-sql-truncate-and-sql-delete-statements-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to construct the statement without a nested `select`:

```
SET @SQL = '
TRUNCATE TABLE _result.result
WITH (PARTITIONS [partitions])';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[partitions]',
                   STRING_AGG(PartitionNumber, ', ')
                  )
FROM #temp2;

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```